# Complex domain validation via Symfony Forms & Constraints

Tags: php, symfony, validation, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I have several complex Domain objects. And I use Symfony forms for validating REST requests over them. Let's assume, I have domain **Banner**. And I have endpoints for creating/updating the concrete banner by ID with **BannerFormType**. **Banner** has limits: daily and total. The business rule is "both limits are required, but daily should be less or equal than total". So we have a situation, where we should use a custom class-constraint for validating two fields linked with each other.

So, my form looks like:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

class BannerFormType extends \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(\Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('daily_limit', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('total_limit', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType::class, [
                'constraints' => [
                    new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(\Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Banner::class,
            'constraints' => [
                new BannerLimits(),
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

We code of that constraint looks like:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App;

class BannerLimitsValidator extends \Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($banner, \Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint $constraint): void
    {
        if (!$banner instanceof Banner) {
            throw new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException($banner, Banner::class);
        }

        if (!$constraint instanceof BannerLimits) {
            throw new \Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, BannerLimits::class);
        }

        /** @var \Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form */
        $form = $this->context->getObject();

        $totalLimit = $form->get('total_limit')->getNormData();
        $dailyLimit = $form->get('daily_limit')->getNormData();

        if ($totalLimit < $dailyLimit) {
            $this->context
                ->buildViolation('Daily limit should be less or equal than total.')
                ->atPath('daily_limit')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except that we have a very coupled validator. If we want it to reuse for other form, there will be a problem. For example, I would like to add bulk endpoint for updating banners, so it will use **BannerListFormType**.

Of course, I could pass fields data inside constraint via options, but it's hard to do for a nesting forms.
Also, I could call a validator directly inside form event, but it looks strange.

Also, with my approach, it's hard to unit test validator with *\Symfony\Component\Validator\Test\ConstraintValidatorTestCase* because of coupling constraint with form structure.

What could you advice to me? How you guys solve such a problem?

Comment: I would have set the custom validator to the class level not via the form. https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator

Comment: Anyway I deal with this by not using forms at all for a rest API. I prefer using DTO's and validate both DTO and the Entity.

Comment: That's the same approach but different ways. This do not solve my problem with a coupled validator. Mb this is not a problem?

Comment: I think not, because by setting the constraints in the domain entity you skip the form complexity. The object can be validated outside or inside a form context. You can unit test your contraints and assume the validation will be the same in any form you would use.
The coupled validation is not realy an issue in my point of view. You could write a dynamic validator that take two properties names, and compare them with reflection but if need this once in my project I would write a specific Validator just for that case.